# Way to ALTER DATABASE OPEN from READ ONLY to READ Write

Tags: database, oracle

Once I open the Database using "ALTER DATABASE OPEN READ ONLY" mode, how can I change the status of the db to "OPEN READ WRITE" without shutting it down?

After opening my database in Read Only mode and finishing my task I issued "ALTER DATABASE OPEN READ WRITE" statement which showed error below:

"a database already open by the instance".

Can a Database that is in Read-Write mode be changed to Read-Only and Vice Versa?

Thanks & looking for help.

Comment: FORCE option:
Specify this keyword to change the open mode of a PDB from READ WRITE to READ ONLY, or from READ ONLY to READ WRITE. The FORCE keyword allows users to remain connected to the PDB while the open mode is changed.

When you specify FORCE to change the open mode of a PDB from READ WRITE to READ ONLY, any READ WRITE transaction that is open when you change the open mode will not be allowed to perform any more DML operations or to COMMIT." 

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ALTER-PLUGGABLE-DATABASE.html#GUID-A29491AD-8F0F-4E52-9D94-57FC3FF8FBC7

Comment: What version is this and what is the configuration? Is this a plug-in database or a standalone database?

Comment: Thanks. The version of the DB is oracle 12c, Release 2 & It's a standalone database.

Answer (score 0):

### `READ ONLY` and `READ WRITE` are [modifiers of the same `ALTER DATABASE OPEN` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/multi/administering-pdbs-with-sql-plus.html#GUID-817703E2-B3E8-486F-8E3D-CFBB38911813).

Since an instance can only mount and open one database at a time, you have three options:

1. The following statement changes the open mode from *mounted* or *open read-only* to *open read/write* : `ALTER DATABASE OPEN FORCE;`
2. To shutdown the instance, then start it in the mode you'd like, either by a `SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE` then a `STARTUP OPEN READ WRITE` or a `STARTUP FORCE OPEN READ WRITE`.
3. <strike>To close the instance, then open it in the mode you'd like. That you can do with an `ALTER DATABASE CLOSE IMMEDIATE` (you can check that the DB went to `MOUNTED` mode using `SELECT status FROM v$instance;`) then an `ALTER DATABASE OPEN READ WRITE`.</strike>

*Note: Option 1 works when you want to change the open mode from read-only to read-write. Options 2 & <strike>3</strike> however, do work in both directions.*